# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuth' of undefined when implemeting authentication to React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the context API to implement authentication, but I cannot figure out where my problem, i'm getting error when trying to render Register component, here is my code:

> Register.js

```
 import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { AvForm, AvGroup, AvInput, AvFeedback } from 'availity-reactstrap-validation';
    import { AuthConsumer, useAuth }  from '../AuthContext';

    const Register = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ email: '', password: ''})
    const handleChange = (e) => setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })


    return (
    <React.Fragment>
          <Container>
              <AuthConsumer>
                { ({ isAuth, signup }) => (
                  <AvForm onSubmit={signup.bind(this, user, props)} onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit}  className="authentication-form">

                 <AvGroup className="">
                      <Label for="email">Email</Label>
                          <InputGroup>
                              <AvInput onChange={handleChange} type="email" value={user.email} placeholder="email" name="email"/>
                          </InputGroup>
                  </AvGroup>

                  <AvGroup className="mb-3">
                    <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                        <InputGroup>
                            <AvInput onChange={handleChange} type="password"value={user.password} placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                        </InputGroup>
                </AvGroup>
                  </AvForm>
                        )}
                      </AuthConsumer>
            </Container>
    </React.Fragment>

  )
}

export default Register
```

> AuthContext.js

There is a code sample of authcontext that i used: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p71pr7jn50?file=/src/AuthContext.js)

***Error log:***

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuth' of undefined
 at Register.js:39
 at updateContextConsumer (react-dom.development.js:18206)
 at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18556)
```

Register.js:39

```
   <AuthConsumer>
  >>         { ({ isAuth, signup }) => (
               <AvForm onSubmit={signup.bind(this, user, props)} 
 onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit}  className="authentication-form">
```

Comment: Please include the full error and any stack trace provided.

Comment: @BrianThompson My bad, updated